# TFLite dynamic input shape

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I am using [TensorFlow 2.1](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf) and trying to use variable-length input sequences for a recurrent neural network after conversion to [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite). I first converted my [Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) model to [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite) model using [TFLite Converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_keras_model). I built the model with input shapes [(None, 40), (1, 6, 2, 32)]. But after conversion into [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite), the model accepts only input shape [(1, 40), (1, 6, 2, 32)]. I want my [TFLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite) model to accept variable values for None. I tried to resize my tensor input using [resize_tensor_input](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#resize_tensor_input), but still the shape of the input is not changing. 
I have pasted my code snippet and its output below.

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=my_model_path)

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()

interpreter.resize_tensor_input(0, [3, 40], strict=False)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]["index"], np.random.uniform(size=[3, 40]).astype(np.float32))
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]["index"], np.zeros(shape=[1, 6, 2, 32]).astype(np.float32))
tf.print("Input details : ", input_details)

interpreter.invoke()

result = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]["index"])
final_state = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]["index"])
```

I printed my input details inside the code pasted above and the output is pasted below. Here I am getting my first input shape as [1, 40] instead of [3, 40].

```
Input details :  [{'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 0,
  'name': 'input_1',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([ 1, 40], dtype=int32)},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 1,
  'name': 'input_2',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([ 1,  6,  2, 32], dtype=int32)}]
Output shape : (1, 1, 32)
Final state shape : (1, 6, 2, 32)
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code? Or if my approach to achieve the desired result is wrong, please help me to find the right method to achieve the same, or is there any other workaround for the same?

Comment: What happens with recent version such as TF 2.3 or tf-nightly?

Comment: Hi I have tried with tf2.3. Same problem. However not tried with tfnightly

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I meet the same issue using TF 2.6

Comment: I am faceing the save problem here. Any updates?